# Unable to change the Fore color of DataGridview cells

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winforms application that was designed in the next manner:
Shell Form (Main form) with panel control shows child forms on it by clicking on buttons .

```
    private void btnInbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenChildForm(new InboxForm(), sender);            
    }

    private Button currentButton;
    private Form activeForm;

    private void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, object btnSender)
    {
        if (activeForm != null)
        {
            activeForm.Close();
        }
        ActivateButton(btnSender);
        activeForm = childForm;
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panelDesktop.Controls.Add(childForm);
        this.panelDesktop.Tag = childForm;
        childForm.BringToFront();
        childForm.Show();

    }
```

In the InboxForm I have the DataGridView (dgvRequests) and in Load event of InboxForm, I'm realizing RefreshDGV() method

```
private void RefreshDGV()
    {
        //Loading requests from Requests table   to DGV
        SQL_Queries_Inbox q = new SQL_Queries_Inbox();
        dgvRequests.DataSource = q.Get_RequestsFromSql();

        dgvRequests.Columns["ID_Request"].Visible = false;
        dgvRequests.Columns["Purchasing Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvRequests.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvRequests.Rows[i].Cells["Purchasing Date"].Value);

            if (dt.Year < 2002)

            {
                dgvRequests.Rows[i].Cells["Purchasing Date"].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { ForeColor = Color.Transparent, SelectionForeColor = Color.Transparent };

            }
        }


    }
```

My trouble is that the Fore color of the needed cell doesn't change, but if I create a new form with the same DataGridview and realize the same Refresh DGV() method everything works fine

[The date 01/01/2001 must be transparent and unvisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y54yQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using CellFormat event of the DataGridView

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewGetCellStyle
{
    public partial class DatesForm : Form
    {
        private readonly DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle
        {
            ForeColor = Color.Transparent,
            SelectionForeColor = Color.Transparent
        };
        public DatesForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgvRequests.CellFormatting += dgvRequestsOnCellFormatting;
        }

        private void dgvRequestsOnCellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex != 1) return;
            if (dgvRequests.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) return;

            if (!DateTime.TryParse(dgvRequests.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Purchasing Date"].Value.ToString(), out var date)) return;
            dgvRequests.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Purchasing Date"].Style = date.Year < 2002 ? dataGridViewCellStyle : null;
        }

        private void DatesForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dgvRequests.Rows.Add("Jim Smith", new DateTime(1999, 1, 1));
            dgvRequests.Rows.Add("jane Adams", new DateTime(2010, 1, 12));
            dgvRequests.Rows.Add("Bill North", new DateTime(2022, 1, 13));
            dgvRequests.Rows.Add("Karen Payne", new DateTime(2001, 1, 14));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, in this way, everything works fine, but I still do not understand what is the reason that if I create the independent new form with the same DataGridview and realize the same Refresh DGV() method everything works without CellFormat event, but when this form as childform, I need CellFormat event?

Comment: @Yan only way I could accurately tell you why is to have a full copy of your project from a GitHub repository.